# How to change the hover state for CardActionArea / ButtonBase

Tags: material-ui

I'm currently using the CardActionArea / ButtonBase Material Ui @next components for my app.

I can't seem to change the onhover effect that comes with the button.

I also can't seem to find the selector that is causing the background overlay color on hover. Can anyone help with this?

https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/

https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/

I've tried setting a backgroundColour in the className prop, classes prop (applied to `root`/`focusVisible`/`focusHighlight`) but with no luck.

Demo that might better explain what I'm trying to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/jnnr5wo029

Expected result: onHover style would be overridden / disabled with css

Actual result: Grey onHover style is still applied

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/CardActionArea/CardActionArea.js#L15) focusHighlight has opacity applied to it on hover. You can override this to remove the hover effect e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/j3zw9w7yk9

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should've done some more digging into the source code.